# Alarm/Vibration acting erratically if the phone is locked?

Tags: java, android, android-alarms, android-vibration

I am working on an alarm/vibration based app which alarms 10 minutes before a specified time and 2 minutes before a specified time.

Both alarms are set to vibrate for 30 seconds and this is working when the phone remains unlocked.

However, when the phone is locked and the last alarm vibrates it is only vibrating for maybe 5 or 6 seconds?

Has anyone ever encountered this problem before?

**UPDATE:**

> It is when the phone is locked and say the phone lights up because of the vibration but then once the screen goes dark again, THAT is when the vibration stops

Code:

```
 public void startAlert(View view) {

    if (timeAllowedOut.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error, text missing!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {

        removedDate = new Date();
        timeRemovedText.setText(almacDateFormat.format(removedDate.getTime()));
        time1 = String.valueOf(timeRemovedText);
        time2 = String.valueOf(timeAllowedOut);
        VisualAlert.calculate();
        mTime1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        mTime2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        mTime1.setTime(firstAlarmTime);
        mTime2.setTime(secondAlarmTime);

        //Set the 10 before to alert exactly 10 minutes before time
        tenBefore =mTime1.getTimeInMillis();

        //set 2 minutes before to not alert for seconds, therefore alerting at wall time.
        twoBefore = trimSecsAndMillisecs(mTime2).getTimeInMillis();
        removedTime = removedDate.getTime();

        i = tenBefore != null ? tenBefore.intValue() : null;
        j = twoBefore != null ? twoBefore.intValue() : null;

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(VisualAlert.this);
        //Set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Set alarm");
        //set Dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Desiccants removed at \n" + almacDateFormat.format(removedTime))
                .setCancelable(false)
                //if this button is click, set Alarm
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //set Alarm manager
                        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

                        //Hide desiccant exposed until bottled clicked
                        btnExposed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        btnBotttled.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        // set both alerts if time allowed out greater than or equal to 10 minutes
                        if (removedDate.before(firstAlarmTime) || removedDate.equals(firstAlarmTime)) {
                            intent = new Intent(VisualAlert.this, MyAlarm.class);
                            intent1 = new Intent(VisualAlert.this, MyAlarm2.class);

                            //sending information to the broadcaster
                            intent.putExtra("extra", "exposed");
                            intent1.putExtra("extra", "exposed");

                            //set first alarm
                            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(VisualAlert.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, tenBefore, pendingIntent);


                            //second alarm
                            pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(VisualAlert.this, j, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, twoBefore, pendingIntent2);
                        }
                        //only set the second alert if time less then 10 minutes
                        else {
                            intent1 = new Intent(VisualAlert.this, MyAlarm2.class);
                            intent1.putExtra("extra", "exposed");
                            pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(VisualAlert.this, j, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, twoBefore, pendingIntent2);

                        }
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //if this button is click, do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        //create alert Dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        //show it
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}


//Stop alarm, with all alert forms ending
public void stopAlert(View view) {

    i = tenBefore !=null ? tenBefore.intValue() : null;
    j = twoBefore !=null ? twoBefore.intValue() : null;

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(VisualAlert.this);
    returnedDate = new Date();
    //Set title
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Desiccant bottled");
    //set Dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
            //Set alert dialog to display time desiccant was bottled.
            .setMessage("Desiccants bottled at \n" + almacDateFormat.format(returnedDate.getTime()))
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    //Hide desiccant exposed until bottled clicked
                    btnExposed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btnBotttled.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    reset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    //intent to class
                    intent = new Intent(VisualAlert.this, MyAlarm.class);
                    intent1 = new Intent(VisualAlert.this, MyAlarm2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("extra", "bottled");
                    intent1.putExtra("extra","bottled");

                    //pending intent to awake device
                    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(VisualAlert.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(VisualAlert.this, j, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
                    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent2);

                    sendBroadcast(intent);
                    sendBroadcast(intent1);
                    timeBottledText.setText(almacDateFormat.format(returnedDate.getTime()));

                    //change returnedDate and removedDated to Calendar
                    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.setTime(returnedDate);
                    cal.setTime(removedDate);

                    //Calculate time elapsed (not accounting for seconds)
                    long diffInMilliSec = trimSecsAndMillisecs(calendar).getTimeInMillis() - trimSecsAndMillisecs(cal).getTimeInMillis();
                    long diffInMin = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diffInMilliSec);
                    String total = String.valueOf(diffInMin);

                    if (returnedDate.before(removedDate)) {
                        totalTimeText.setText("--");
                    } else {
                        totalTimeText.setText(total);
                    }

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //if this button is click, do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    //create alert Dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    //show it
    alertDialog.show();
}

//Update alert time when 'time allowed out'  is changed
private TextWatcher mTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        //not needed (Method must be overridden)
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        //not needed (Method must be overridden)
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable view) {
        calculate();
    }
};

// Trims a Calendar object of its seconds and milliseconds
private static Calendar trimSecsAndMillisecs(Calendar cal) {
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    return cal;
}
```

Alarm:

```
  if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH));


    //fetch the extra string values
    String state = intent.getExtras().getString("extra");
    Log.e("ringtone state:extra is", state);


    //this converts the extra strings from the intent
    //to start IDs, Values 0 and 1
    assert state != null;
    switch (state) {
        case "exposed":
            startId = 1;
            break;
        case "bottled":
            startId = 0;
            break;
        default:
            startId = 0;
            break;
    }

    //if else statements
    if (!this.isRunning && startId == 1) {
        Log.e("if there was not sound1", " and you want to start");
        //incorporate vibrating
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        //create as instance of the media player
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tick_tock_sound);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);

        v = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        long[] pattern = {0, 100, 10};
        v.vibrate(pattern, 0);
        ;
        if (v.hasVibrator()) {
            Log.v("Can Vibrate", "YES");
        } else {
            Log.v("Can Vibrate", "NO");
        }

        //turn flash light on
        camera = Camera.open(0);
        parameters = camera.getParameters();
        parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.startPreview();

        createNotification(this, "Warning", "2 minutes to bottle Desiccants", "Alert");

        this.isRunning = true;
        this.startId = 0;

    } else if (!this.isRunning && startId == 0) {
        Log.e("if there was not sound", "and you want to end");
        this.isRunning = false;
        this.startId = 0;
    } else if (!this.isRunning && startId == 1) {
        Log.e("if there is sound", "and you want to start");
        this.isRunning = true;
        this.startId = 0;
    } else {
        Log.e("if there is sound", "and you want to end");
        v = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        //stop song playing
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();

        try {
            releaseCameraAndPreview();
            camera = Camera.open(1);
            parameters = camera.getParameters();
            parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "failed to open Camera");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //stop vibration
        v.cancel();

        this.isRunning = false;
        this.startId = 0;
    }

    Log.e("My Activity", "In the service");

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: I think ive give you all you need @vinS. Check updated pos

Comment: further update added @vinS